# ps2pdf -dEPSCrop stops short with pstricks \uput

Tags: pstricks, ps2pdf

Basically `ps2pdf -dEPSCrop` doesn't crop to the full extent specified and stops at some mysterious point. I'm trying to trim the white space on the left of the image but `-dEPSCrop` stops short irrespective of the value I give to the lower left bounding box coordinate of the pspicture environment variable.

Please find a not-so-MWE at: http://pastebin.com/MYAJtLUu

Here's the file stripped of all but the `\uput`'s:

```
    \documentclass[english,landscape,a4paper]{slides}

    \usepackage{graphics}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{babel}
    \usepackage{pst-eps}
    \usepackage{pstricks}
    \usepackage{multido}
    \usepackage{pst-node}
    \usepackage{pst-math}
    \usepackage{pstricks-add}

    \begin{document}
        \begin{TeXtoEPS}
            \begin{pspicture}(2,-2.966)(12.064,0)
            \psset{linejoin=1}
            \newcommand{\verysmall}{\fontsize{9}{9pt}\selectfont}
            \verysmall
                    \uput{0.2mm}[180](2.349,-1.66){$s$}
                    \uput{1mm}[225](2.522,-2.043){$c$}
                    \uput{1mm}[-110](4.067,-.9){$b$}
                    \uput{0.25mm}[-45](8.405,-2.671){$a$}
                    \uput{0mm}[0](11.808,-1.66){$t$}
                    \uput{1mm}[100](4.799,-1.199){$d$}
                    \uput{0.5mm}[90](8.653,-2.597){$e$}        
            \end{pspicture}
        \end{TeXtoEPS}
    \end{document}
```

I'm trying to create cropped PDF images from pstricks graphics. My workflow is as follows:

```
    latex NoSoMWE.tex
    dvips -E NoSoMWE.dvi
    ps2pdf -dEPSCrop NoSoMWE.ps NoSoMWE.pdf
```

Lately however, `ps2pdf -dEPSCrop` no longer works when the pstricks file makes use of the `\uput` directive. Cropping however works when all `\uput`'s are removed from the not-so-MWE. Cropping does not work if at most *one* `\uput` directive is used.

Please advise, thanks.

Comment: I have no problem with your example ... However, using `xelatex` or package `auto-pst-pdf` makes more sense. Using `pst-eps` is a bit outdated.

Comment: Same here. Compiled under TeXLive 2011, `dvips` 5.991 and GPL `Ghostscript` 8.71 on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your objective is

- to get a standalone PDF output without excessive white spaces
  surrounding it, and
- to import the resulting PDF from within your main (La)TeX input file

then the remaining paragraphs might be useful for you.

In this answer, I assume you are a Windows user. If it is not the case, you have to adapt the given MS-DOS batch files (also known as make file in other OS).

> WARNING: I also assume that the TeX input file, that is used to
>   produce the standalone PDF output, does not load `animate` package.
>   Why? Because the animation in the standalone PDF output will **NO
>   LONGER** work when it is imported into your main TeX file by using
>   either `\includepdf{}` or `\includegraphics{}`.

I will use the following image in this answer, name it `hen.jpg`.

[image]

I will divide into 2 cases based on whether or not an input file, that is used to produce a standalone PDF output, imports images. If you don't import images in the input file, that is used to produce a standalone PDF output, then the division is not important but you should choose the faster one!

### Case 1

This compilation is much much faster than the compilation that will be discussed in Case 2.
However, you cannot use this work flow if your input file imports any image of type PDF, PNG and/or JPG. If you only import EPS images or you don't import any image, you should choose this work flow because the compilation is much much much faster!

Create a batch file, name it `DevLa.bat`, to compile an input file that is used to produce a standalone PDF output.

```
rem It takes an input file name WITHOUT extension.
echo off

del %1.pdf

rem latex %1
latex %1
dvips -D10000 -t unknown %1
gswin32c -r10000 -dCompatibilityLevel=1.5 -dAutoRotatePages=/None -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=%1.pdf %1.ps

del %1.log
del %1.aux
del %1.dvi
del %1.ps
```

For simplicity, you can save it in the same directory in which the input file exists. If you want to reuse this batch for other project, then you need to setup PATH environment variable.

The following MWE `withoutimage.tex` (which does not import images) can be compiled with `DevLa.bat`

```
% withoutimage.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,multido}
\SpecialCoor
\psset
{
    linecolor=red,
    arrows=->,
    arrowscale=1.5 0.75
}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewBorder=0pt
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}

\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)
        \psframe[linecolor=red](-2,-2)(2,2)
        \multido{\i=0+30}{12}
        {%
            \psline(0.9;\i)
            \uput{1}[\i]{\i}(0,0){$\i^\circ$}%
        }
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

by invoking

```
DevLa withoutimage
```

And you will get a tight PDF output as follows.

[image]

### Case 2

This compilation is much much slower than the compilation discussed in Case 1. However, you can use this work flow if your input file imports any image of type PDF, PNG, JPG and/or EPS. If you only import EPS images or you don't import any image, you should choose the work flow in Case 1 because its compilation is much much much faster!

Create a batch file, name it `DevXe.bat`, to compile an input file that is used to produce a standalone PDF output.

```
rem It takes an input file name WITHOUT extension.

echo off

del %1.pdf

rem xelatex %1
xelatex %1

del %1.log
del %1.aux
```

For simplicity, you can save it in the same directory in which the input file exists. If you want to reuse this batch for other project, then you need to setup PATH environment variable.

The following MWE `withimage.tex` (which does import a JPG image) can be compiled with `DevXe.bat`

```
% withimage.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pstricks,multido}
\SpecialCoor
\psset
{
    linecolor=red,
    arrows=->,
    arrowscale=1.5 0.75
}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewBorder=0pt
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}

\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)
        \psframe[linecolor=red](-2,-2)(2,2)
        \multido{\i=0+30}{12}
        {%
            \psline(0.9;\i)
            \uput{1}[\i]{\i}(0,0){\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{hen}}% please adapt it!
        }
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

```
DevXe withimage
```

And you will get a tight PDF output as follows.

[image]

### Importing the stadalone PDF outputs

After getting the standalone PDF outputs, you can import them from within your main input file as follows.

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[hbtp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{withoutimage}
\caption{This is a nice image.}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{figure}[hbtp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1.5]{withimage}
\caption{This is a nice image too.}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

And it can be compiled using either `xelatex` or `pdflatex`.

> If the `main.tex` still have other PSTricks codes with labels, then
>   use `xelatex` because `pdflatex` with `auto-pst-pdf` will break the
>   labels.

And the result is as follows.

[image]

Comment: Why have this useful answer only got 2 votes?